# Multiple threads reading from single folder on Linux

Tags: python, linux, multithreading

My projects needs multiple threads reading files from the same folder. This folder has incoming files and the file should only be processed by any one of those threads. Later, this file reading thread, deletes the file after processing it.

**EDIT after the first answer:** I don't want a single thread in charge of reading filenames and feeding those names to other threads, so that they can read it.

Is there any efficient way of achieving this in python?

Comment: why don't you want to use a single thread to pass input filenames to other threads?

Comment: If I do that, this input reading thread needs to act as a scheduler which feeds the filenames to the free threads. Instead, If there is something out there I can already use which helps me achieve this that would be great.

Comment: @Sujit You're not going to find something that doesn't rely on a work queue model. Why don't you want to use it? I can assure you that it won't be the bottleneck - disk access will be.

Comment: related: [lockfile python libraries](http://packages.python.org/lockfile/lockfile.html#other-libraries)

Comment: @Sujit: You could organize your code that input thread just calls `queue.put(filename)` than a new filename is available (`pyinotify` might help here). Working threads just call `queue.get(filename)` in a loop. Input thread knows nothing about working threads and vice-versa.

Comment: pyinotify and queue looks like the way to go for me. I will keep everyone posted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use the [`Queue` module](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html). From the docs:

> The Queue module implements multi-producer, multi-consumer queues. It is especially useful in threaded programming when information must be exchanged safely between multiple threads.

I would use a FIFO approach, with a thread in charge of checking for inbound files and queuing them, and a number of workers processing them. A LIFO approach or an approach in which priority is assigned with a custom method are also supported by the module.

---

**EDIT:** If you don't want to use the `Queue` module and you are under a *nix system, you could use [`fcntl.lockf`](http://docs.python.org/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.lockf) instead. An alternative, opening the files with `os.open('filename', os.O_EXLOCK)`.

Depending on how often you perform this operation, you might find it less performing than using `Queue`, as you will have to account for race conditions (i.e.: you might acquire the name of the file to open, but the file might get locked by another thread before you get a chance to open it, throwing an exception that you will have to trap). `Queue` is there for a reason! ;)

---

**EDIT2:** Comments in this and other questions are bringing up the problem with simultaneous disk access to different files and the consequent performance hit. I was thinking that [task_done](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.task_done) would have been used for preventing this, but reading others' comments it occurred to me that instead of queuing file names, one could queue the files' content directly. This second alternative would work only for a limited amount of limited size queued files, given that RAM would fill up rather quickly otherwise.

I'm unaware if RAID and other parallel disk configurations would already take care of reading one file per disk rather than bouncing back and forth between two files on both disks.

HTH!

Comment: The question here is, how to read from the same folder and make sure two threads are not reading the same file?

Comment: @Sujit - ...and the answer is precisely about that. What part is unclear?

Comment: I don't want a single thread in charge of reading filenames and feeding the filenames to other threads. Think of it as a lock over a Folder or something. You know what I mean? In your approach, you have a thread in charge of inbound files. I don't want that.

Comment: So you want to share files currently being processed between threads? That sounds slightly dangerous. Use pyinotify to handle file change events in that folder, to catch new files, and add those to a queue as the answer suggests. You can't just say "I don't want to", you need to give reasons.

Comment: @Sujit: is there a particular reason why you don't want a thread managing and doling out the file names to other threads?

Comment: I didn't consider the disk spinning overhead at first. What @Sebastian's suggestion might work for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want multiple threads to read directly from the same folder several files in parallel, then I must disappoint you. Reading in parallel from a single disk is not a viable option. A single disk needs to spin and seek the next location to be read. If you're reading with multiple threads, you are just bouncing the disk around between seeks and the performance is much worse than a simple sequential read.

Just stick to mac's advice and use a single thread for reading.

Comment: Queue in @mac's suggestion contains filenames, therefore multiple threads may read simultaneously from different files. It is unclear whether it is slower than reading in all files in one thread.

Comment: @mac: there is also file cache, overhead of piping data in Python, etc. I'd choose the lower coupling between threads unless a profiler says otherwise.